# use futex in user space?

Tags: linux, futex

I need functionality of do_futex() call in user space outside of lock/unlock context. I.e., I do not need a mutex, but the exact semantics of the kernel call do_futex.

It would seem it should be available in user space, since the intent was to minimize the number of system calls, but I can't link with it.

Or is there a syscall?

Update:

I'm currently using syscall(__NR_futex, ...) to run do_futex(). But

1. I have to include  to get __NR_futex, which is ugly
2. I have to include  to get FUTEX_WAIT and FUTEX_WAKE, but I still don't get EWOULDBLOCK, or the maximum number of threads for WAKE

Is there a coherent wrapper?

Comment: What exactly do you think the semantics are? When you refer to `do_futex` are you referring to the actual `do_futex` routine in the kernel that is indirectly called by the `futex` system call?

`man futex`

Comment: how do I get the futex system call? I'm doing a syscall(__NR_futex, ...), but this is ugly, and I don't get the futext defines to pass in or compare against. And I have to include <asm/unistd.h> to get __NR_futex. I can include <linux/futex.h> as man suggests, but that defines the kernel call rather than user space call. And it still does not define some of the constants. Is there a consistent wrapper/header?

Comment: `sys/syscall.h`, not `asm/unistd.h`, is the proper header for accessing system calls from userspace. `linux/*` and `asm/*` includes do not belong in userspace apps.

Answer (score 2):

As it's said on http://locklessinc.com/articles/obscure_synch/:

> Finally, in order to block on a kernel wait-list, we need to use the Futex system call, which unfortunately isn't exposed by linux/futex.h.

And they define their own simple wrapper:

```
#include <linux/futex.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>

static long sys_futex(void *addr1, int op, int val1, struct timespec *timeout,
                      void *addr2, int val3) {
    return syscall(SYS_futex, addr1, op, val1, timeout, addr2, val3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

futex(2) system call is probably what you are looking for.

man 2 futex

Also, on side note, man syscalls gives list of all system calls.

Comment: But where is it defined? In which header?

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html mentions that it's linux/futex.h and sys/time.h